# Stuck on NPE Assigning Array.toString(object) to Another Array in Class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm stuck on an NPE while trying to assign an array object to another array.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class groupData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Group students = new Group(4);
        students.promtNewUser();
   }
}

class Group {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int user_count;
    private int max_users;//maximum number of users
    private String[] directory;//array for list of users
    private String[] user;//array for ind users

   //constructor method
   public Group(int total_users) {
       max_users = total_users;//max_users equals value passed to class with new
       user_count = 0;
       String[] directory = new String[max_users];
   }

   public void promtNewUser() {
        String[] user = new String[4];

        System.out.print("Enter first name:  ");
        String fname = input.nextLine();
        user[0] = fname;

        System.out.print("Enter last name:  ");
        String lname = input.nextLine();
        user[1] = lname;

        System.out.print("Enter phone number:  ");
        String phone = input.nextLine();
        user[2] = phone;

        System.out.print("Enter age:  ");
        String age = input.nextLine();
        user[3] = age;

        add_user(user);
   }

   public void add_user(String[] user) {
      if (user_count == max_users) {
         System.out.println("Sorry, the group is full!");
      }
      else {
        directory[user_count] = Arrays.toString(user);
        System.out.println("User added to group!");
        user_count++;   
      }

  }
```

}

And here is the output in terminal after compiling and running through the prompts:

```
Enter first name:  Winston
Enter last name:  Churchill
Enter phone number:  +44 1 3425 9989 834
Enter age:  143
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Group.add_user(groupData.java:53)
    at Group.promtNewUser(groupData.java:45)
    at groupData.main(groupData.java:8)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a badly written code and a badly phrased question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Group` class you specify a `String[] directory`

```
class Group {
    // ...
    private String[] directory;//array for list of users
```

Then in your `Group` constructor, you declare a new local variable with the same name, effectively hiding the class variable:

```
//constructor method
public Group(int total_users) {
    // ...
    String[] directory = new String[max_users];
```

When you construct your `Group`, the class variable never gets initialized and remains `null` and the local variable is created, assigned and never used. Then later on you attempt to index into the class `directory` variable but it is `null`:

```
public void add_user(String[] user) {
    if (user_count == max_users) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, the group is full!");
    }
    else {
        directory[user_count] = Arrays.toString(user); // HERE:  directory is null
        System.out.println("User added to group!");
        user_count++;   
    }
}
```

Fix the `Group` constructor by initializing the class variable instead of a local variable:

```
//constructor method
public Group(int total_users) {
    max_users = total_users;//max_users equals value passed to class with new
    user_count = 0;
    directory = new String[max_users]; // removed the String[] type, so you are now referencing the class variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt!  That solved it.  When I run my program now using your suggestion, I get: `User added to group!`.  Appreciate your help.